# Вызов функций native библиотек из QtScript

Tags: c++, qt

Всем доброго времени суток!
Для своего проекта использую Qt Script. Возникла проблема: вызвать из скрипта функцию из библиотеки написанной на С. Чтение документации не помогло. Погуглив я выяснил, что скриптовые языки Luа(LuaJIT), Python и Ruby такое умеют. Более того все эти языки используют библиотеку libffi для native вызовов. Собственно вопрос: умеет ли QtScript такое (я в скриптах не силен)? Если да - то как воспользоваться? Если нет - то может кто-то уже пробовал прикручивать libffi к QtScript? Поделитесь опытом: может знаете какие могут возникнуть проблемы/грабли? Сразу скажу, что пересаживаться на другой скриптовый язык не хочется - очень подкупает возможность использования QObject в скрипте напрямую.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно это можно реализовать через [QTScript extensions](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtscriptextensions.html).

Comment: Да, возможно именно этим путем я и пойду, но интересно больше сама реализация такого плагина. В любом случае - спасибо за ответ!